# Show/Hide a 'new' badge on newly added ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and i want to show an ImageView (the new badge) on the list item if it has been recently added.

[Like so:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWmvv.png)
So i have added a boolean isNew in my model class:

```
public class Item {
private String name;
private String profession;
private boolean isNew = true;

//Constructor
public Item(String name, String profession) {
    this.name = name;
    this.profession = profession;
}

//Getters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public boolean isNew() {
    return isNew;
}

//Setters
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}

public void setNew(boolean aNew) {
    isNew = aNew;
} }
```

The 'new badge' is an ImageView and its visibility is set to GONE by default.

Then, I in my adapter i have an if statement that checks if the isNew boolean for the particular item is true or not and based on that it makes the 'new badge' (ie. the ImageView, VISIBLE) by calling ImageView.setVisibility()

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private List<Item> items;
private Context context;


public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_list_item, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);

    //Binding the views from the single_item_layout
    TextView mName = view.findViewById(R.id.mName);
    TextView mProfession = view.findViewById(R.id.mProfession);
    ImageView new_badge = view.findViewById(R.id.new_badge);

    //Get the data from the List
    Item item = items.get(position);

    //Setting the data
    mName.setText(item.getName());
    mProfession.setText(item.getProfession());

    //Make 'new_badge' VISIBLE if the item is new
    if (item.isNew()){
        new_badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //Return the view
    return view;
} }
```

Then in the main_activity I have a ListView OnItemClickListener and in that i have defined that when a list item is clicked the boolean for that specific item is set to false, and then i call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ListView
private ListView mListView;

//ArrayList
static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

//Adapter
ItemAdapter itemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing the ListView
    mListView = findViewById(R.id.mListView);

    //Adding Data to the ArrayList of items
    items.add(new Item("Danyl Fernandes", "Developer"));
    items.add(new Item("Henry Yuming", "Web Designer"));
    items.add(new Item("Ashley Janberg", " Park Naturalist"));
    items.add(new Item("Mary Almen", "Civil Drafter"));
    items.add(new Item("Carola Traino", "Insurance Appraiser"));
    items.add(new Item("Daniela Mocanu", "Infantry Officer"));
    items.add(new Item("Jaden Labuguen", "Surveyor"));
    items.add(new Item("Zaketa Nichola", "Petroleum Engineer"));

    //Initializing the Adapter
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items);

    //Set the Adapter to the ListView
    mListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    //Handle ListItem Clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             Item item = (Item) mListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
             item.setNew(false);
             itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
} }
```

So this works fine and when any item is clicked the NewBadge disappears 
[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xMWy.png)

***But the Problem is*** when i restart the app all of the songs show as new again, even the one i clicked on already shows the 'new badge'

[Here's a Github link to the entire project:](https://github.com/gitryder/NewBadgeList)

Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of the code you wrote. You don't save the state of your items. And when you restart your app you create new items. of course they are all new again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you start the app again all items are gonna be new, since you don't save anything :)

I would recommend using a database to manage all the items. That way you will be able to save when you click a new person, and the 'new' will not appear again.

If I can recommend a library for this, use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

This is an example how your table model could look like:

```
@Entity
public class Item
{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Profession")
    public String profession;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "New")
    public boolean new;
}
```

Comment: This is actually a mock application just to test this 'new badge' feature. The real project that I'm working on uses a Firebase Real-Time Database so i can't store the flag in the database, because then it would change for all the users and if one user clicks isNew would be set to false for all the users.

Comment: But coming back to using Room, Im a beginner and Ive only heard about Room. So my question is that if i happen to have 100 listview items, then there would be 100 room database entries for all of them (correct me here), wouldnt that be storage heavy? It would take up space overtime as the number of listview items grow, right?

Comment: Then your mock-up works, because clicking the item does what you need it to do! Using Room in this case would help you store the state for each device.

If you have 100 list view items, or 100 objects rather, then you would have 100 entries in your `Item` table. It's SQLite, so it's just a normal database. So it doesn't get any more storage heavy compared to anything else. :)

Comment: Thanks, it helped alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because whenever you are restarting the application, you are creating a new set of items always. Once a class is destroyed it clear all the temporary data. To see the changes in an item you have to save them and change the flag of that item in the database whenever user click on an item.